# For each vs for every

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “each” and “every”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6656/difference-between-each-and-every)

I'm not sure if I should use *for each* or *for every* in the quoted sentence.
On one hand it sounds better to use *for each*, on the other hand, I think when talking about how often something happens we must use *for every*.

> 1 . Employee A has a shift planned for each of the 5 days in a row.
>    2 . Employee A has a shift planned for every of the 5 days in a row

Which one do you think is the right one here or is there any other way for stating that ?

Comment: I'm still in doubt about which one should I use.

Comment: For your specific example I would use neither. "For the next 5 days" is more idiomatic.

Comment: But at this specific example I'm not properly talking about the next 5 days, but in any period with 5 sucessive days of work.

Comment: So you're saying "For any set of 5 days, Employee A has a shift planned."? That's the same as saying "Employee A works every day." because there is no day that Employee A doesn't work.

Comment: @MattЭллен I think he means he wants a statement applicable to any five-day period, not every five-day period

Comment: Zeno Vendler (1967) "_Each_ and _Every, Any_ and _All._" in his book of
essays, _Linguistics in Philosophy_, Cornell University Press.

Comment: Employee A has a shift planned for 5 contiguous days in a row

Answer (score 5):

You're right in thinking that "*every*" would be awkward there -- in fact, grammatically impossible. For the following reasons:

1. We do **not** say "*every of*." But we can say "*every **one** of*."

   On the other hand, you can say "*each of*."
2. We indeed use "*every*" but not "*each*" to talk about frequency.
   But this doesn't make your second sentence correct.

   To talk about frequency in particular, we say: *every day*, *every Monday*, *every 5   days* etc.
3. The first sentence is grammatically acceptable up to the phrase "*of the 5 days*." Like this:

> Employee A has a shift planned for each of the 5 days.

But I have to warn you that this might not mean what you want it to mean, especially because you mentioned "*frequency*."

Answer (score 4):

You have three ideas:

1. There is a **specific** set of five days, expressed by your '**the** 5 days'
2. The five days are **consecutive**, expressed by '**in a row**'
3. Employee A is called for **all** of those days, expressed by 'Employee A has a shift planned **for each of**'—observe that 'every' may not be used here because unlike 'each' it is never used as a substantive, only as an adjective. You may say, as @CoolElf points out, 'every **one** of', or you may say as I do '**all** of', but not 'every of'.

The awkwardness arises from your use of 'in a row'. You treat this as an adjectival phrase modifying 'the 5 days', and this is entirely proper. You've covered ideas 1 and 2.

**However**: there is a competing, and I should guess more common, use of '# Y in a row' as an adverbial phrase—'He went to church 5 Sundays in a row'. This use embraces both idea 2 and idea 3. If you say 'Employee A is called for 5 days in a row', 'each' or 'all' is redundant. **But**: this use does not accommodate idea 1 gracefully—its intension is consecutivity (idea 3) and comprehension (idea 2), and 'for **the** 5 days in a row' just isn't English idiom.

So you're presenting your reader with two competing parsings of 'in a row'. What you need to do is either replace 'in a row' as your lexicalization of idea 2 or eliminate the second parsing by displacing idea 1. Which you choose depends on where you want to put your focus. Your '**the**' implies that the date in question has already been specified, so something like one of these:

1. Employee A has a shift planned for all of these five consecutive days.
2. Employee A has a shift planned for five days in a row at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Employee A has a shift planned for 5 days, each and every day.