# "a capacity limit for each warehouse" or "capacity limits for every warehouse"

Tags: differences

I am not really sure whether I understand these phrases correctly.

"a capacity limit for each warehouse" means that each warehouse has its own limit, which may be different from other warehouses' limits??

"capacity limits for every warehouse" means that each warehouse has more than one limit and that set of limits of a warehouse is the same as the other sets of different warehouses??

Do I understand these correctly???

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the word each is generally used in situations where we consider the Warehouses individually or sequentially, whereas every and all are used for generalizations.

So I think you have understood it but failed to express it. Please refer to this [link] ([Difference between "each" and "every"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6656/difference-between-each-and-every?rq=1))

Answer (score 0):

You're correct about how many limits both phrases imply, though I have to say that in both cases the difference compared to other warehouses can vary. If it specifically meant that all the warehouses had the same set limit, then it would be phrased as ' one capacity limit for all warehouses'. Well...at least that's the way I understand things.