# When are 'each' and 'every' not equivalent?

Tags: word-usage

'I gave each child an apple' and 'I go there every year' sound correct to me, while the same sentences with 'each' and 'every' swapped sound wrong. Why is this so?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/each-or-every  This link might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Difference between 'each' and 'every'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6656/difference-between-each-and-every) ?

Comment: 'I go there each year' sounds OK to me, though less usual. It's as though you are thinking of the years individually, but each one includes a visit to that place.

Comment: _Every_ is just the count singular of plural _all_: _All the boys are sick ~ Every boy is sick_. _Each_, on the other hand, is more complex, because it refers to a 1-to-1 relationship of some sort, either of boys to apples, or of effects to causes. _I gave every boy an apple_ could but probably doesn't mean sharing one apple among all the boys. _I gave each boy an apple_ means 1 boy, 1 apple only.

Comment: It's mainly a matter as to which is idiomatic in a given context.

Comment: 'I gave each child an apple' *and* 'I go there every year' *sound correct to me, while the same sentences with 'each' and 'every' swapped sound wrong. Why is this so?* I don't think it is possible to answer: both versions of each sound fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, *each* is used with an identifiable set. In *I gave each child an apple* this is clear as the set of children you gave apples to is known to you and will not change. Conversely, since we've no way of knowing which years are specified in *I go there every year*, it would be unnatural to use *each* in this sentence. Even you, the speaker, have no way of knowing the exact set of years here as it's expressed as a state which continues indefinitely.

Also, the distributive meaning is stronger with *each*. In *I gave each child an apple* there would seem to be clearly differentiated acts of giving involved, as opposed to, say, giving one big basket of apples to a group of children. Though I'd say *I gave every child an apple* could still have the same interpretation.

As to your question about when *each* and *every* are not equivalent, there are some clear limits on when exchanging one for the other is acceptable, and when it is not.

*Each was given an apple.*

*
*Every was given an apple.*

*I gave each of them an apple.*

*
*I gave every of them an apple.*

As you can see, *every* cannot be used as a fused determiner-head. If we insert *one* into the sentences above, the ones with *every* become acceptable again.

*I go there practically every year.*

*
*I go there practically each year.*

*Every* can be modified, but not *each*.

*The two children came and each one was given an apple.*

*The two children came and every one was given an apple.*

In the first sentence, it seems that we are talking about the two children who came as *each* may be used with a set of two. In the second sentence it doesn't seem to be the two children only that we're talking about as *every* is not acceptable with sets of two.

*They were hanging on his every word.*

*
*They were hanging on his each word.*

Following a genitive determiner, *every* is acceptable, but not *each*.

Comment: In addition, "each" can end a NP but "every" can't: *The children were given an apple each* is OK, but *The children were given an apple every* is not.