# Difference between every and each

Tags: word-choice, differences

> 1. Jack has been to a lot of parties this month. He enjoyed (every - each) one of them.
> 2. There are 3 glasses, but (each-every) one has a different shape.

In the answer guide, the two questions​ are answered as 'every' but why?

> If the sentence focuses on the group as a whole, the answer will be every while if the sentence focuses on the individuals, the answer will be each

But how can I know whether the sentence focuses on the group or the individuals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "each" and "every"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6656/difference-between-each-and-every)

Comment: Personal choice -- to every his own.

Answer (score 1):

'Every' considers all the individual items as a collective; 'each' considers all of the individual items individually.

'Every house in our street has blue door' vs 'Each house in our street has a door of a different colour.

'I will be speaking to each of you about this'............meaning speaking individually rather than as a group.

Your examples:
1- 'Jack has been to a lot of parties this month. He enjoyed each one of them' ...........(when comparing the individual parties.)

2- 'There are 3 glasses, but each one has a different shape'........(when comparing the three individual glasses.)

Comment: Okay but in the example I written it's not clear whether it's talking about the group or the individuals, how can I know?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But are these sentences also correct with every? As in the answers they are both " every " so can they be answered as "every" or is it just a mistake?

Comment: I do it instinctively, but if the sentence includes the use of  'one', that is a good indicator.  Also , I disagree that the party sentence is every. Are you sure that is correct in your guide? I would say: 'he enjoyed them all'.

Comment: The guide is usually correct. But I also answered both of them  "each" and I didn't know how they can be "every". Maybe this is a mistake.

Comment: 'I enjoy every party I go to.' (I enjoy them all).  But in your example the use of 'one' is directing you to consider the parties individually rather than as a whole.  I´m an English teacher so I may be wrong or not able to see a valid solution to this.

Comment: Okay great, so both examples should be "each" , right?

Answer (score 0):

'Each one' takes turns cooking dinner in the evenings.

Each stresses individual members of a group.
Each refers to two or more people who share the work.
AND
'Everyone' takes turns cooking dinner in the evenings.

Every stresses all the members of the complete group.
Every refers to three or more people.

Comment: I understand , but in the guide both examples are answered " every " so can they be answered as "every" or is it just a mistake?